# Messy to get the workflow of the @+ operator for the following program in perl

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$var="HELPLINE108";
$var=~m/\w+(\d+)/g;
print "@+";
```

1. i get confused the work flow of the above pattern matching because it outputs as 11 11.Why the 11 11 appears twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is `HELPLINE108`. And then your pattern is `/\w+(\d+)/g`.This pattern matches the whole string by `\w+(\d+)`

Output of the pattern is `11 11`

The first `11` reports the last position of the entire match. And then second `11` matched from the grouping of `(\d+)`

For example

I write the pattern for same string.

```
/HE(LP)LINE1/g;
#9 4
```

`9` from the position of the entire match from the string.

`4` from the position of grouping.